# Using Enquire.js and Media Queries Effectively for Jquery Animations

Tags: jquery, media-queries, show-hide, enquire.js

Hi i've been trying to get my head around how to use enquire.js. I am using .mouseenter(function() to activate the functions .show and .hide. But when you view it on a tablet and mobile .mouseenter becomes redundant. I want to tell the jquery to show  the div once the screen width reaches my media query.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 769px ) and (max-width : 959px)
```

Below is an example.

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".slidingDiv_how").hide(); 
          $(".show_sub").show(); 

          $('.show_sub').mouseenter(function(){
          $(".slidingDiv_how").slideDown();
            return false;
          });
            });
```

Here is my html

```
<div class"right-wrapper"><!--How wrapper -->
                                <div id="how_we" class="show_sub1" style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;">
                                    <h1><a href="#">How We Work:</a></h1>
                                        <div class="slidingDiv_how">
                                            <p class="show_sub1">The heat of the vertical rays of the sun was fast making our horrible prisons unbearable, so that after passing a low divide, and entering a sheltering forest, we finally.</br> 
                www.dochouse.co.uk</p>

                                        </div> <!-- end slidingdiv2 -->
```

I have read the documentation and don't really understand which part to put were. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, pretty much copied straight from the [docs](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width : 769px ) and (max-width : 959px)", {
    match : function() {
        $(".slidingDiv_how").show();            
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        $(".slidingDiv_how").hide();
    }
}).listen();
```

Note change for latest version

> v2.0.0 (2013-04-17)
>
> listen and fire are no longer needed as of v2, and have been dropped
>   from the API. Removing any usage of them in your code is all that is
>   required. Also, as enquire no longer relies on resize events you must
>   make sure your polyfill supports matchMedia.addListener. Details of
>   this can be found in the legacy browser section.